# Structure of Closed Semialgebraic set

Tags: real-algebraic-geometry, semialgebraic-geometry

I am trying to prove the following, from Benedetti and Risler's book:

[image]

The "above proposition" is:

[image]

It seems an easy proposition that boils down to taking the complement of the complement of F, since the complement of $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: P(x)>0\}$ is $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: P(x) \leq 0\}$. But I end up with a finite intersection of unions of sets of this form, and I can't rewrite it as the intended form. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but I hope my answer is still helpful. In fact, a finite intersection of unions of sets can be rewritten as another finite union of intersection of sets because:
$$\bigcap_{i \in I}\bigcup_{j \in J} \{x\mid P_{ij}(x) \geq 0\} = \bigcap_{(j_1,\ldots,j_{|I|}) \in J^I}\bigcup_{i \in I} \{x\mid P_{i,j_i}(x) \geq 0\}.$$